# How to employ UTC in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

In an Inno Setup script I have a string created from the current time that I store in the registry. I do like this:

```pascal
function GetInstallDateTime (s : String ) : String;
Var 
   year, month, day, nr1, nr2 : String;
   sum : Byte;
   error: Integer;

begin   
   year := GetDateTimeString ('yy', #0, #0);
   nr1 := Copy(year, 1, 1);  
   nr2 := Copy(year, 2, 1);
   year := nr1+nr2;

   month := GetDateTimeString ('mm', #0, #0);
   nr1 := Copy(month, 1, 1);  
   nr2 := Copy(month, 2, 1);
   month := nr1 + nr2;

   day := GetDateTimeString ('dd', #0, #0);
   nr1 := Copy(day, 1, 1);  
   nr2 := Copy(day, 2, 1);
   day := nr1 + nr2;

   hour := GetDateTimeString ('hh', #0, #0);
   nr1 := Copy(hour, 1, 1);  
   nr2 := Copy(hour, 2, 1);
   hour := nr1 + nr2;
   Result := year + month + day + hour);
end;
```

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\Testprogram\Settings"; ValueType: string; \
  ValueName: "mrg"; ValueData: {code:GetInstallDateTime|''}; \
  Flags: deletekey;
```

The problem is that I need to have the string made from UTC time. Is there anyone who could tell me how I could do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can simplify and replace all lines between `begin` and `end` with this single line: `Result := GetDateTimeString('yymmddhh', #0, #0);` Refer to [documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=getdatetimestring)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already know *(based on your [alternative attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51640826/850848))*, you can use [`GetSystemTime` WinAPI function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemtime):

```pascal
type
  TSystemTime = record
    wYear: Word;
    wMonth: Word;
    wDayOfWeek: Word;
    wDay: Word;
    wHour: Word;
    wMinute: Word;
    wSecond: Word;
    wMilliseconds: Word;
  end;

procedure GetSystemTime(var lpSystemTime: TSystemTime);
  external 'GetSystemTime@kernel32.dll';

function GetInstallDateTime(Param: string): string;
var
  SystemTime: TSystemTime;
begin
  GetSystemTime(SystemTime);
  Result :=
    Format('%.2d%.2d%.2d%.2d', [
      SystemTime.wYear mod 100, SystemTime.wMonth, SystemTime.wDay, SystemTime.wHour]);
end;
```

---

*`GetSystemTime` declaration is from ISXKB (not defunct).*