# Inno script can't read dll function

Tags: inno-setup, pascal

I have in Inno Script a call to a dll function made in Visual studio C++ Express. But I keep getting an error message saying "could not call proc" error 6:16. I believe I have done the setup just as instructed:

```
[Files]    
Source: "C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 
2010\Projects\Testprogram\Release\Utctime2.dll"; DestDir: "{app}";  Flags: 
dontcopy

[Code]
function Utc(): Integer;
external 'Utctxt@Utctime2.dll stdcall delayload';

function GetInstallDateTime (s : String ) : String;
Var 
  Text : String;
  Integer : Number;
begin
  Number := Utc();
  Text := IntToStr(Number);
  Result := Text;
end;

[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\Testprogram\Settings"; ValueType: String; 
ValueName: "mrg"; ValueData: {code:GetInstallDateTime|''}; Flags: deletekey;
```

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

here's the code of the C program:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Utc.h"

int WINAPI DllMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD fdwReason, PVOID pvReserved)
{
    return TRUE ;
}

EXPORT BOOL CALLBACK Utctxt ()
{
  CHAR Time[10];
  int DateTimeTable[5];
  int count;
  SYSTEMTIME UTime;   
  count = 123;
  /*
  GetSystemTime(&UTime);
  DateTimeTable[count]   = UTime.wMinute;
  DateTimeTable[++count] = UTime.wYear - 2000;          
  DateTimeTable[++count] = UTime.wDay;
  DateTimeTable[++count] = UTime.wHour;             
  DateTimeTable[++count] = UTime.wMonth;         
  */  
  return(count);
}
```

The only purpose of the program is to get a string representation of UTC time, as the pascal version in Inno Script only gives local time. For now, however, I just let it return an integer, just for testing.

I know that a similar question has been asked before, but I believe I have done exactly what the answer says.

Comment: I don't have a `utctime2.dll` on my Windows 10 Pro system. Where does it come from in order for the setup process to find it when it's being run?

Comment: I have made it myself.

Comment: Again, *Where does it come from in order for the setup process to find it when it's being run?* It doesn't matter if it's on your machine, because you don't need to run the installer on your machine. Where does the **machine that's running the installation** find the DLL if it's not part of Windows?

Comment: Additionally, post a log file from the latest version of Inno Setup + Show us your C++ declaration of the function.

Comment: It would also help, if you share the DLL with us. Or some dummy implementation.

Comment: Ken, I am not quite sure what you are looking for, but the dll file is in the directory where all the other files are that makes up the setup file. "C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testprogram\Release\

Comment: It should be `external 'Utctxt@file:Utctime2.dll stdcall delayload';` (note `files:` prefix) + `DestDir: "{app}"` is useless (it's ignored) and confusing.

Comment: Though I'm pretty sure you can implement your function directly in Pascal Script.

Comment: I see now that you have asked that already: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51525753/850848, but you didn't use [tag:inno-setup] tag. I've answered that question.

Comment: *"I know that a similar question has been asked before, but I believe I have done exactly what the answer says."* - No you didn't. Did you read my comments above? You are missing `files:` prefix - Moreover, you do not need a DLL for this at all, as my answer to your other question shows.

Comment: I tried to use the prefic "files", but it didn't help.

Comment: Sorry, Martin, I saw now that you have answered the question about utc time in Inno Script. I will try it out. Thanks.

Comment: @martinprikryl The answer you gave about getting UTC time inside of Inno Script worked. Thank you very much. Problem solved. I don't need to use another self made dll.